# Accessing data in widget

Tags: design-patterns, python, gui

**Background**

I started to get involved in a project written in python and wxPython (for the GUI). My task is to debug and add a few features to the GUI.

The widgets are organised mainly with *sizers*, and the application as a whole only looks good at a certain screen size and resolution.
First thing I did was to group some elements under some panels and separate them with *splitter* (`wx.SplitterWindow`). But the hierarchy of the widgets changed; in one line of code I had to change from:

```
class CustomGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, config):
        # ...
        self.data = self.GetParent().data
```

to:

```
class CustomGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, config):
        # ...
        self.data = self.GetParent().GetParent().GetParent().data
```

That's ugly. In another instance a widget class get inserted in two different places and the *data* is not located at the same *parent* level.

**Questions**

I am suspecting that there is something wrong with the architecture here. 
How to/Should I separate the data from the GUI?

Any tips and/or links to blogs or other questions would be nice to get started with. Also how to state my question better? (I'm looking forward to learning the proper lingo and perhaps edit the title!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Relative (parent-children) widget resolution is... ugly**. It makes your code set in stone and GUI unchangeable. All your widgets must be isolated from each other as much as possible.

I suggest keeping track of all relevant objects in a dictionary.

```
_widget_dict = {"oranges_grid": oranges.grid, "apples_window": apples.mywindow}
```

This is akin to **GtkBuilder in GTK+ - by keeping a reference in a book you are able to easily access them by supplying a name.

```
def get_widget(widget_id):
    return _widget_dict[widget_id]
```